# Calculus: Find $\lim\limits_{h \to 0}{\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}}$ for $f(x)=\cos(x^2)$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Find the limit:

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$

Given that $f(x) = \cos(x^2)$

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you allowed to recognize this as the derivative and use the chain rule, or are you supposed to do this the hard way, and basically rederive the chain rule and the derivative of $\cos$ at the same time?

Comment: What have you attempted thus far?

Comment: i think the chain rule will be acceptable

Comment: Then did you try to use the derivative?

Comment: i have seen some similar question which is the same expression but it switches f(x) = cos (x^2). Is it the same kind of calculation?

Answer (score 0):

This is the definition of the derivative of $f(y)=\cos (y^2)$ at the point $y=x$. So, 
$$
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=f'(x)=-2x\sin(x^2)
$$

Comment: Thank you for helping

Answer (score 0):

The derivative can be found by first principles.

Method: use sum to product identity.
$$
\begin{align*}
\lim_{h \rightarrow0}\frac{\cos(x+h)^2-\cos x^2}{h} &= \lim_{h \rightarrow0}\frac{-2\sin(x^2+hx+h^2/2)\sin(hx+h^2/2)}{h} \\
&=\lim_{h \rightarrow0}-2\sin(x^2+hx+h^2/2) \frac{\sin(hx+h^2/2)}{hx+h^2/2}\frac{hx+h^2/2}{h} \\
&=\lim_{h \rightarrow0}-2\sin(x^2+hx+h^2/2) \frac{\sin(hx+h^2/2)}{hx+h^2/2}(x+h/2)\\
&=-2\sin(x^2)(1)(x)=-2x\sin(x^2)
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Thank you for helping

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$

Let $f(x) = \cos(x^2)$, then

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\cos((x+h)^2)-\cos(x^2)}{h}$$
Apply L'Hopital's Rule
$$\lim _{h\to 0}\left(\frac{-2\sin \left(\left(x+h\right)^2\right)\left(x+h\right)}{1}\right)$$
$$ \lim _{h\to 0}\left(-2\left(x+h\right)\sin \left(\left(x+h\right)^2\right)\right)$$
$$-2\left(x+0\right)\sin \left(\left(x+0\right)^2\right)$$

> $$-2x\sin \left(x^2\right)$$

You can also apply the [Chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule):
$f(g(x)) =  (f\circ g)'=(f'\circ g)\cdot g'$, where in your case $f(x) = \cos(x)$ and $g(x) = x^2$

> $$f(g(x)) = \cos(x^2) = -\sin(x^2)\cdot2x = -2x\sin(x^2)$$